# Where Can I Find "WinBase.H"

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, turbo-c++

I am using turbo c++ 4.5, and intend to read and write file using `Win32 API`. I've applied `CreateFile()`, but it shows an error:

> "Call to undefined function".

I think I need Winbase.h file.

Comment: Turbo is pretty outdated. MinGW and Visual Studio will both easily have it.

Comment: you need a more modern compiler. visual c++ is free.

Comment: Turbo C++ is a 20 years old compiler. Why are you using it?

Comment: To be more precise: Turbo C++ 4.5 targets 16-bit Windows, which didn't have a function named `CreateFile` (it was new with Win32). To target 32-bit (or 64-bit) Windows, you *need* to use a newer compiler.

Comment: Thanks.I need 2 change the compiler !